# Nhibernate stores id=0 as null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have small problem with nHibernate (fluent) I have two objects, one contains another - a parent and a child (predefined objects, readonly).

mappings:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual ChildClass Metoda { get; set; }
}

public ParentClassMap() {
        Table("Wyceny");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
        References(x => x.Metoda).Column("RMW_ID");
}

public ChildClass 
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nazwa { get; set; }
}

public ChildClassMap()
{
            Table("Metody");
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
            Map(x => x.Nazwa).Column("Nazwa_met");
}
```

Everything works perfectly until I chose child object with id = 0, reading still works for id=0, but when I'm trying to save or update Parent with correct ChildObject(readed previously from db through nHibernate), nHibernate stores null instead of value.

Any suggestions?

nHibernate 3.3.1.4000
fluent 1.4.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here would be the `unsaved-value`. NHibernate must decide if operations with object will be insert or update. This decision comes from `unsaved-value` setting, which is by default for `int` set to 0.

Try to extend your mapping of a `ChildClass`:

```
public ChildClassMap()
{
   Table("Metody");
   Id(x => x.Id)
       .Column("Id")
       .UnsavedValue(-1);
   ...
```

See [5.1.4. id](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id), cite:

> `unsaved-value` *(optional - defaults to a "sensible" value)*: An identifier property value that indicates that an instance is newly instantiated *(unsaved)*, distinguishing it from transient instances that were saved or loaded in a previous session.

And here is nice [Id mapping](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/02/mapping-by-code-id-naturalid.html) overview by Adam Bar *(the second half of the article)*

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy NHibernate ;)